# How do I get all members with a certain role discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have my command `.roleinactivity @whatever role`. How do I take whatever role that was pinged and find all of the members that have that role?

I've been trying to loop through each member in the server with an if statement to see if they have said role but it didn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the users with your role by using `.members`:

```py
@client.command()
async def roleinactivity(ctx, role : discord.Role): 
    print(role.members)
```

`role : discord.Role` - transforms your role argument to `discord.Role` object to make it work properly. Otherwise, it would get recognized as `string`.

[`discord.Role` in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role)